# php - Form item not being posted

Tags: php, sql

Here's the relevant snippet of my form

```
<form action="viewtickets.php" method="post">
            <label for="ticketid">Ticket:</label>
            <input type="text" id="ticketid" name="ticketid" disabled>
</form>
```

In `viewtickets.php` I am trying to run this query:

```
$query=mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE ticket
                         SET mgrid = '$_SESSION[mid]',
                         status = 'claimed'
                         WHERE ticketid = '$_POST[ticketid]'");
```

I'm getting an udnefined index error for the posted `ticketid`

I tried `WHERE ticketid = 1` to test it and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that your input field is disabled:

```
<input type="text" id="ticketid" name="ticketid" disabled>
```

This means, that there is no `ticketid` available in your `$_POST`, just remove it and it will work.

If you just want to show the `ticketid` to the user, without the ability for the user to change it you should use the attribute [readonly](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp).

By the way, you should take a look at [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) for you sql.